# Algorithm to "fill" trees

Tags: algorithm, tree

I'm looking for the best way to fill requirements depicted by a series of trees, and a map of data. A basic tree might look like this:

```
  10
 /  \
A    B
```

And a map of data might look like this:

```
A: 7
B: 6
```

In these examples, the 10 represents a requirement, while the data list is what I have to work with. So, I could "fill" this tree by giving it 4 `A`s and 6 `B`s, or 5 of each, etc. Now, I want to use all the `A`s and `B`s available to me, and having a surplus isn't necessarily an issue (so I'm going to give 7 and 6 in this case), but things get more complicated; we can have multiple trees, and trees can have multiple levels, where each node but the leaves are requirements, potentially giving us something like this:

```
      40                           30
   /   |   \                      /  \
  20   C    D                    A    C
 /  \
A    B
```

So we would need the `A` and `B` on the first tree to add to 20, the `C` and `D` on the first tree to add to twenty, and the `A` and `C` on the second tree to add to 30. (No tree should have the same letter appearing twice.) We can have any number of levels in a tree, or any number of trees.

Lastly, our data set may not be perfect. It may not be possible to fill both trees up all the way after optimization (we might have both trees falling short of their requirements, we might have one tree surpassing requirements while the other falls short, etc.) What I need is a way to, given these trees and a list of how many `A`s, `B`s, `C`s, etc. we have available, fill up as many trees as possible. We've been at this for a while, but none of us are good enough at proofs to say "this way will work every time".

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: (Would you try and describe a greedy approximation?)

Answer (score 0):

It a Max Flow problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem
But you need to modify graph.
You have a source. Source are connected to your resources (A, B, C) by edges. Throughput of this edges is amount of the resources. Then you connect all your trees to resources. You modify your trees so node throughput goes to outgoing edge throughput
And then outputs of your trees goes to one destination node.